# Security concerns with PHP mail script, no user input fileds

Tags: php, security, email

I have one php file which sends me an email every time it's loaded. There is no user input fields, it is not contact form or any other form. It's just a redirect php file and I want to receive email each time it is loaded. I have included following php mail function in it and wonder if there are any security issues with it (since there are no user input fields I am hoping I can leave it like this):

```
   $to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the file is loaded';
$message = 'the file loaded, check it out';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@mywebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@mywebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From functionality perspective this is perfectly safe. Your e-mail can't be altered.

However, if one person decides to troll you, he can send you an incredible amount of e-mails in a very short time. Your host or ISP will get pissed over this.

You can avoid this with queueing. Get a database or a file, save the amount of times the page is called and when the last e-mail is sent.

If the script is called AND the last sent e-mail is x minutes ago, you can send yourself a message that the page has been called x times. Then, you just empty the database and restart counting :)

---

Here's a script to get your started (haven't tested)

```
// Duration in seconds
$duration = 60 * 15;

$now = time();
$file = 'tmp.json';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));

array_push($json['calls'], $now);

// It appears it's time to send the content
if($json['sent'] + $duration > $now) {
    $to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the file is loaded';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@mywebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@mywebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $message = '';

    // Generate message
    foreach($json['calls'] as $c) {
        $message .= sprintf("File loaded at: %s\r\n", date('r', $c));
    }

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        // Reset the file but ONLY if the mail was sent
        file_put_contents($file, json_encode(array(
            'calls' => array(),
            'sent'  => $now
        )));
    }
} else {
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
}
```

Comment: Thank you much for your answer and suggestions. I doubt someone will troll me since there are no links anywhere on the Web to this file, but just in one specific location, password protected and accessible to just one person so this file gets loaded only 2,3 times per year, but is very important to me that I am notified immediately when it's loaded. Thanks!

Comment: @user3021391 Oh, in that case you don't really have to check when it was last sent. I still wrote a script for you or whoever may find this question :)

Answer (score 0):

What security issues may there be with an email that has static content which you posses full control over. Anyway I believe it would be better if you just kept track of your file loads in a local file or a database. Good luck! `:P`